# Why pod errors after installing Stripe pod and using Stripe in code objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stripe-payments

I'm following this [ios](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/ios) link to integrate Stripe in my iOS `Objective-C` project.

I have installed pod successfully. But when I use

```
@import Stripe;
```

to import, it gives me error `"Module 'Stripe' not found"`. But if I use

```
#import <Stripe/Stripe.h>
```

or

```
#import "Stripe.h"
```

there is no error of `"Module 'Stripe' not found"` but so many pod errors appear.

[image: errors image]

[image: another errors image]

Errors give me fix suggestions but after fixing more errors appear. What is the reason if these errors and how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Did you try clean build the project

Comment: yes i tried many times but not effect